# Use DataTable to show 50 rows from Database with ability to search entire database

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a table in my database to keep track of specifications:

```
| specs |
id
spec_name
url
common_spec
notes
```

In this table are about 8,000 specs. There are about 100 of these specs that I use often while the rest I need on hand in case the need to use them arrives. I use DataTables to show the specs that are marked as a common_spec. Those specs have a '1' in the common_spec column.I have a table structured like this:

```
<?php $specs = $specslist->get_specs(); ?>
<table id='commonSpecs'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Spec Name</th>
<th>Notes</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($specs as $spec): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $spec['spec_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $spec['notes']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#commonSpecs').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength" : 100
    });
</script>
```

The MySQL query is:

```
public function get_specs(){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("
        SELECT specs.url, specs.spec_name, specs.notes, specs.id FROM specs WHERE specs.common_spec = 1 GROUP BY specs.id ORDER BY specs.spec_name");
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

I am trying to show these 100 specs marked common specs in the table when I first open the page, but allow the ability to search the entire table of 8,000 specs.

Can anyone give me a direction to go? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***

The idea here is to avoid loading all of the rows from the table and only loading the rows that initially meet certain criteria (is a common_spec) and then allow a search of the entire table when/if the initial set doesn't have the spec. Hopefully this all makes sense.

Comment: You can find a good example in the datable documentation http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `GROUP BY`.  It's only useful for summary queries, containing functions like `SUM(column)` or `MAX(column)`.

You may want this:

```
     SELECT specs.url, specs.spec_name, specs.notes, specs.id 
      FROM specs
  ORDER BY specs.common_spec = 1 DESC, specs.spec_name
     LIMIT X,Y
```

`ORDER BY specs.common_spec = 1 DESC` will fetch out your common specs first in your result set.  The expression `specs.common_spec = 1` has two possible values, 1 and 0.